# Creating dataframe from a nested python dictionary of keys, sub-keys, and lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe using parts of a nested dictionary containing keys, sub-keys, and lists. I can create a dataframe with the keys and sub-keys I need, but I can't figure how to pull in the lists that are associated with the sub-keys.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
medical_code_dict = {'Cardiac': {'snomed': ['123456789'],
                                 'icd10': [],
                                 'icd9': ['V12.3'],
                                 'loinc': {'125-6':['234','567','890'],
                                           '542-0':['098','765','432']}},
                      'Stroke': {'snomed': [],
                                 'icd10': ['Z12.3'],
                                 'icd9': [],
                                 'loinc': {}},
                      'Blindness': {'snomed': [],
                                    'icd10': [],
                                    'icd9': [],
                                    'loinc': {'345-7':['345','780']}}}
```

I would like to create a dataframe of the loinc code info, including the lists. I can get part of the way there by doing this:

```
loinc_test_1 = {}

for key in medical_code_dict.keys():
    loinc_test_1[key] = (medical_code_dict[key]['loinc'])

loinc_test_2 = {}

for k,v in loinc_test_1.items():
    for x in v:
        loinc_test_2.setdefault(x,[]).append(k)

loinctable = pd.DataFrame(loinc_test_2.items(), columns=['loinc', 'SDOH'])

loinctable

     loinc   SDOH
0    125-6   [Cardiac]
1    542-0   [Cardiac]
2    345-7   [Blindness]
```

But I can't figure out how to pull in the lists into the dataframe. I would like the output to look like this:

```
    loinc   SDOH         response
0   125-6   [Cardiac]    234
1   125-6   [Cardiac]    567
2   125-6   [Cardiac]    890
3   542-0   [Cardiac]    098
4   542-0   [Cardiac]    765
5   542-0   [Cardiac]    432
6   345-7   [Blindness]  345
7   345-7   [Blindness]  780
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing key structure is constant, here is a naive approach:

```
import pandas as pd

medical_code_dict = {'Cardiac': {'snomed': ['123456789'],
                                 'icd10': [],
                                 'icd9': ['V12.3'],
                                 'loinc': {'125-6':['234','567','890'],
                                           '542-0':['098','765','432']}},
                      'Stroke': {'snomed': [],
                                 'icd10': ['Z12.3'],
                                 'icd9': [],
                                 'loinc': {}},
                      'Blindness': {'snomed': [],
                                    'icd10': [],
                                    'icd9': [],
                                    'loinc': {'345-7':['345','780']}}}

buf = []

for key in medical_code_dict.keys():
    loinc = medical_code_dict[key]['loinc']
    if loinc.keys():
        for l_key in loinc.keys():
            for l_val in loinc[l_key]:
                buf.append({'loinc' : l_key, 'SDOH' : key, 'response' : l_val})

df = pd.DataFrame(buf)


>>> df
        SDOH  loinc response
0    Cardiac  125-6      234
1    Cardiac  125-6      567
2    Cardiac  125-6      890
3    Cardiac  542-0      098
4    Cardiac  542-0      765
5    Cardiac  542-0      432
6  Blindness  345-7      345
7  Blindness  345-7      780
```